# Block Notepad from editing

Tags: printing, notepad, dot-matrix-printer

I generate a document in .txt format (because the document is printed with an old dot matrix printer).

The problem is: User edit some data before printing the document, thats why I want to find some way to block Notepad edit (users only use notepad for print documents).

I tried setting up readonly, but it only locks from saving edited file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not possible. You need to disable notepad (and probably wordpad as well) and find another way to print.

Comment: Perhaps explain the user workflow more, but short of writing some sort of "printing" app, this isn't going to be possible as commented.

Comment: Only practical way to do something like this is to have two user accounts - one with write access to the file, for you to use to edit the file, and one for the user, who only has read access. Assuming that is indeed what you are trying to do - you haven't given much information about your problem.